# AdMob Server Side Validation for Video Reward

Tags: go, admob, tink

I need to verify the video reward of a user on the server, I'm using  Google's Admob and as the documentation found on their website I can't find anything that could help me doing that kind of stuff, as the Golang API is not documented and I also need to use the Crypto Lib used by them, also made by Google, Tink.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I finished this job myself.

Use this [hiyali/go-lib-ssv](https://github.com/hiyali/go-lib-ssv), hope to save your life :)